# Importing Modules using "../" makes builds fail in TravisCI

Tags: javascript, travis-ci

I have this puzzling issue which I don't understand:

If I import modules using '../' it makes my build fail in TravisCI. This is really strange, as it works just fine if I clone the repository and run `yarn install` and `yarn build` myself.

Link to the repository: https://github.com/laurajuliette/yourtime.zone

Log from Travis:
https://pastebin.com/sU9kr42C

Thanks a ton, been trying to solve this all afternoon/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import ScrollToTop from "./helperfunctions/scrollToTop";
```

change to

```
import ScrollToTop from "./helperfunctions/ScrollToTop";
```

inside App.js

Also

```
import NameUserTimezone from "../helperfunctions/nameUserTimezone";
```

change to

```
import NameUserTimezone from "../helperfunctions/NameUserTimezone";
```

I would go through your files to make sure that each import is to the correct path.  (This is case-sensitive)

Also:

- A big help would be to add eslint (I see you have a `.eslintignore` file, but no `.eslintrc`)
- [eslint-plugin-import](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import) This is a great plugin to help prevent these problems

This is also the history view of the commits that changed this import.
[Commit History](https://github.com/laurajuliette/yourtime.zone/commit/b4d9a93fa881a45e01f3a3a7f484424f00a823bb#diff-14b1e33d5bf5649597cdc0e4f684dadd)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I appreciate it. I changed this, but the Travis error seems to persist:

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../helperfunctions/nameUserTimezone' in '/home/travis/build/laurajuliette/yourtime.zone/src/ContentPages'`

Comment: @JuliettePretot I have updated my answer to hopefully help with the problem!

Comment: thanks so much for your help Zach, that was super lovely! I figured out the issue, which was that on my local machine I changed nameUserTimezone.js encodeEvent.js to have a lower case character in the beginning. I imported them as such. For some reason though git did not sync the renaming, leading to incoherent imports. Phew! So glad I figured it out, thanks a ton! You rock.

Comment: RE eslint, I'm actually using it! It's part of create react app, just hidden. Since the code was coherent on my local my machine though, no error was thrown .